# How do I assign a default UTC date value to a DateTime column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like the default value of a DateTime column to be the date 2000-00-00 00:00:00 UTC

What is the function to create this date?

Comment: Well, for starters, that *isn't* a date. There is no 0th month or 0th day. A more sensible default might be January 1st.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alter table YourTable add constraint DF_YourTable_Col1 default '2000-01-01' for col1
```

Comment: as yes of course!! how stupid of me. It is getting late, I should go to bed. Thank you.